# Transaction Records of MtGox?

Tags: mtgox

When transactions are done on [MtGox.com](http://mtgox.com), [MtGox Live](http://mtgoxlive.com) will reflect the transactions by showing "popups" (top-right corner).

Does MtGox provide a "history record of transactions" which show us information of all transactions (timestamp and amount traded) done in MtGox?

I've looked into the [HTTPv1 API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1) but there doesn't seem to be an option to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** I think I found what you are looking for here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1#Multi_currency_trades

Also you can consider following the Streaming API which lets you stream all activity in real time: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming

If the API does not offer this option, I don't think they offer it in an other format.

Although, look at f.e. this page of BitcoinCharts.com: http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/mtgoxEUR_trades.html

They seem to have access to this data somehow. I see that MtGox publishes its full depth. Maybe BitcoinCharts just checks the depth at regular points of time and calculates the trade history from the difference.
You could consider doing the same for your purpose.

Answer (score 6):

As said on https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1#Multi_currency_trades you can use:

https://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/trades?raw

or

https://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/trades?since=0

to get all the historical data.

There's also a non-official Python script (using this API) and a SQLite database with all the historical data, you can find it on:

http://cahier2.ww7.be/bitcoinmirror/phantomcircuit/

The 167MB SQLite database should already have all the data you need, and the Python script in the same directory allows you to update it in real time.

Comment: btw the wiki seems to be silent about the "properties" key. Do you know what "properties":"limit,mixed_currency" mean?

Comment: mixed_currency is about the kind of trades you want to get, for example only USD<->USD trades, or also trades that matched other currency orders ( USD<->EUR for example ) with the 2.5 % conversion fee added

Comment: does anyone know who the author of the SQLite mirror script is?

Comment: phantomcircuit developped the script long ago, I m just hosting a mirror of the script and updated database